# Can't remote via WinRm from non-domain-joined client to domain-joined host, using domain account

Tags: powershell, winrm

Transport listener seems to be good as I can actually create a:

```
$testSession = New-PSSession `
-ComputerName server.domain.net `
-Credential $([System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new("temptestdomain", $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'TEst@123!@#' -AsPlainText -Force))) `
-UseSSL `
-SessionOption $(New-PSSessionOption -SkipRevocationCheck)
```

That seems to work fine, but when the user and password I is:

domain\user
and
PAssword

I get access denied.  I review gpedit and did wildcard for trusted hosts, enabled basic auth and reviewed:

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI -Name Microsoft.PowerShell
```

All looked fine and still...local user added to admin group, works...but domain user added to admin group, does not.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://woshub.com/using-psremoting-winrm-non-domain-workgroup/

Things to check:

- Make sure the account you are using is a member of the remote computer Administrators group.
- Did you run `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` to make sure winrm is properly running? If that gives you any issues use `winrm -quickconfig`
- Since the computer is probably in a workgroup, you will need to authenticate using NTLM (TrustedHosts) or SSL certificates, the link above will guide you further.

Try this and let me know if it helps.